# I have a 3d-Flip-CSS-jQuery inquiry

Tags: jquery, css, 3d

Grr...My company wants to duplicate [**this site's**](http://bananacafe.com.br) 3d image flip for a project:

Does anyone know a simple plugin that will work? I made one that flips the images fine, but this one seems to have boxes with images on one side and text on the other. The "thickness" of the boxes is what I'm missing.

Comment: This page works with transforms in CSS. Look for styles of the kind .csstransforms3d.preserve-3d  . And, by the way, doesn't work in IE.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out after throwing it in IE10. I might just use this to deter them from doing this project at all. It's a bit of an eye sore.

Answer (score 0):

Try the flippy plugin.

Code looks like this:

```
$(".flipbox").flippy({
    color_target: "red",
    duration: "500",
    verso: "woohoo"
});
```

[Description](http://blog.guilhemmarty.com/flippy/)

[Download](https://github.com/lepixel/flippy)

Comment: Thanks for that. I saw this earlier, but it just looks like a 2D flip effect. Is the depth option the thickness? I couldn't get this script to work, it doesn't seem to have a complete script example.